# Possible to run/create 3d animation without need for webgl in HTML5?

Tags: html, css, 3d, webgl

We're trying to find a solution to running/creating 3d animations for use on devices that have no webgl (office computers have weak video cards) and can run on IE8 as a minimum. Of course, no plugins shall be downloaded. We can run HTML5/CSS3 if we use a pollyfil such as css3pie, etc.

Is it just not possible to do 3d stuff with a device that has no webgl support? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [three.js](http://threejs.org/) succesfully with the CanvasRenderer(see Canvas [examples](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_voxelpainter)).

If it helps you can also try some of my older tests:
[image: DeltaBot]
[Delta bots](http://lifesine.eu/labs/three/c4d_deltainc_bot.html)

[image: DeltaCube]
[Delta Cube](http://lifesine.eu/labs/delta/play/geometry_deltacube.html)(refresh for random shape)

[image: Dodecahedrons]
[Dodecahedrons](http://lifesine.eu/labs/three/dodeca.html)

[Diamond geometry explorer](http://lifesine.eu/labs/r61/diamond/d1.html)

It's good to bare in mind that mobile devices might be slower(because there are less resources(CPU/RAM) available to compute and render 3d geometry with canvas, but it's still pretty impressive how much can be done with so little. So textures,special effects, etc. might be slow on mobile, but sometimes limitations lead to original and creative designs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

> The Origami3D Engine is a 3D engine written entirely in JavaScript, using only the 2D context of the Canvas element to render 3D images.
>
> The engine and examples should work in all modern browsers (Chrome 7+, Firefox 3.5+, Internet Explorer 9+, etc), although it might run quite slow in some browsers on certain platforms.

http://projects.mariusgundersen.net/Origami3D/examples/